# How to disable dns prefetch with selenium ruby?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, watir, chrome-web-driver

I'm trying to disable the dns prefetching when running tests with selenium.

I've tried using the arg "--dns-prefetch-disable" on the chromeOptions but nothing happened.

Someone managed to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you set `$DEBUG = true` at the beginning of your test, rerun, and then send me the output? http://gist.github.com would be good if possible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm not sure what input are you looking for. I'm running it locally and after the browser opened I go to "chrome://dns" and look to see that the dns is disabled. Because I run it locally this is the line I wrote: Watir::Browser.new BROWSER.to_sym, :http_client => client, :prefs => $prefs, :args => ["--dns-prefetch-disable"]